# How to create a dictionary using a list?

Tags: python, dictionary, arraylist

I have this list(newList) where I´m trying to create a dictionary with the product as a key and the price(identified with a $) as a value, while the output of the key is correct, the only key that has a value is the last one, and I dont know what I´m doing wrong, I would appreciate some help, thank you.

Here is a resumed version of the code I was trying

```
newList = ["banana", "apple", "$10", "$15"]
dict = {}
product = ""
price = ""
for i in newList:
  if "$" not in i:
    product = i
  else:
    price = i
  dict[product] = price
print(dict)
```

And this is the output:

```
{'banana': '', 'apple': '$15'}
```

Desired output:

```
{'banana': '$10', 'apple': '$15'}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Split the list into two lists, then combine them into a dictionary.

```
products = [x for x in newList if not x.startswith("$")]
prices = [x for x in newList if x.startswith("$")]

product_prices = dict(zip(products, prices))
```

Comment: It says TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable

Comment: That's because you used `dict` as a variable name. Don't do that, it overwrites the built-in function.